# How to insert a javascript file in another javascript at build time using comments

Tags: javascript, build

Is there something on npm or in VS Code or anywhere that can bundle or concatenate Javascript files based on comments, like:

```
function myBigLibrary(){
    //@include util.js
    //@include init.js

    function privateFunc(){...}

    function publicFunc(){
      //@include somethingElse.js
      ...
    }

    
    
    return {
        init, publicFunc, etc
    }
}
```

Or something like that? I would think that such a thing is common when your javascript files get very large. All I can find are complicated things like webpack.

I'm looking for any equivalent solution that allows you to include arbitrary code in arbitrary positions in other code. I suppose that would cause trouble for intellisense, but an extension could handle that.

Comment: Just make your scripts global scoped?

Comment: How does that help me combine them into one file to use as a library?

Comment: Ah, I can do it pretty easy with node, fs, and string replacement. I'm just surprised nobody else has made something simple like this. I will post an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a bare bones way to to what I wanted. I have been learning more about how you can do things with esbuild or other bundlers, but I didn't quite figure out something that fit my needs. And this is simpler and more flexible. It can work for any file type. You can do automatic updates when files change using nodemon instead of node to run this code.

```
const fs = require('fs')
/////////////////////////

const input  = 'example.js'
const output = 'output.js'

const ext    = '.js'

// looks for file with optional directory as: //== dir/file
const regex  = /\/\/== *([\w-\/]+)/g


const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(input).toString()


// replace the comment references with the corresponding file content
const replacement = fileContent.replace(regex, (match, group)=>{

    const comment = '//////// '+group+ext+' ////////\n\n'
    const replace = fs.readFileSync(group+ext).toString()
    return comment + replace

})

// write replacement to a file
fs.writeFileSync(output, replacement)
```

Comment: Note that I changed the format from `//@include` to `//==` and the filename does not need the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really means but if you means linking variables from other javascript files. probably this will help you

`const { variable name } = require(the javascript file path)`

example: 
in index.js

```js
const { blue } = require('./../js/blue.js)
console.log(blue)
```

Meanwhile in blue.js

```
const blue = "dumbass"
```

if this doesnt help you just ignore this

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I'm looking for. I want to *build* a single javascript file out of multiple files, and I need to include code inside other code.